# Word search: my child's parents in law

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an English word to describe the relationship between me and my child's parents in law?

My daughter's father in law is my ...
My daughter's mother in law is my ...

Comment: I think you've got the answer already: "My daughter's father-in-law is my daughter's father-in-law"

Comment: One of them is your ***ex*** the other is your ***ex’s new [husband/ wife]***

Comment: Spanish has words for this relationship.  In  English,  a phrase is necessary, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an English word to describe the relationship between me and my child's parents in law?

- **In current usage, there isn't any**.

My daughter's father in law is ***my daughter's father-in-law***.

My daughter's mother in law is ***my daughter's mother-in-law***.  And that's it.

Some other languages may have a word which is current usage.  In Mandarin Chinese, for instance, the names of family members are usually specified to a very high level.